# Change Owner of Active Directory Object in Python

Tags: python, active-directory

I have a Python app where one of the steps joins the PC to our domain. By default, the object owner for the PC is the username of the person who makes it. While this can be changed in ADSI edit, if possible we would like to be able to programmatically change it, so that the app changes the owner of the object to our specified department group. Could anyone help get me started on this? Looks like it may be doable in VB:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ad/example-code-for-setting-an-ace-on-a-directory-object

Comment: Please provide some codes that shows where you are and what you want to achieve.

Comment: @righteousness_wealth Don't have any codes for it yet. Otherwise I would've put them up there. Description says what I'm looking to achieve. :)